# Can't make remote requests from Sharepoint 2013 event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, dynamics-crm

I have an event receiver in SharePoint and this needs to communicate with Dynamics CRM 2013. It basically checks that user owns the record and if it doesn't creates a task for the record owner.

The problem is that it times out on instantiation of OrganizationServiceProxy, basically on this line:

```
 var service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(url, null, creds, null);
```

I have checked using various browsers that I can get to the Dynamics CRM server, so this is definitely not a problem with networks/firewall.

It seems as if the remote call is being blocked, but blocked by what? I'm guessing some sort of setting on Sharepoint but I don't really know

Anybody knows how to sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the url to dynamics ssl (https)?  If so, make sure you have all of the certs in the certification path of the ssl certificate for the dynamics url loaded into the SharePoint trust center.

Comment: it is, but they both (SharePoint and Dynamics) use the same, wildcard, certificate. 
I'll try hitting the dynamics http instead
thanks

Comment: tried with http and it works with http so i'll add the certs to SP trust centre and try

Comment: Yea, it doesn't matter.  I've always had to add the cert path to my own SP cert for certain loopback requests to work correctly.